# set custom location on tap on screen using flutter_map

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, openstreetmap

I am trying to create a screen where the user can put a custom location using plugin [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map)
open street map free

I have tried several solution but they seems outdated every time I try could you help with it ?

my imports

```
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MapController mapController = MapController();
    List<Marker> markers = []; // List to store markers

    void handleTap(TapPosition tapPosition) {

      setState(() {

      });
    }


    LatLng tapedlan;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('aaa'),),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: FlutterMap(
          options: const MapOptions(
            initialCenter: LatLng(51.509364, -0.128928),
            initialZoom: 3.2,
          ),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              additionalOptions: {
                'style': 'outdoors',
              },
              urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
              userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
            ),
            MarkerLayer(
              markers: markers, // Use the markers list
            ),
          ],
          mapController: mapController,
        ),
        onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => {


        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried this but nothing works

```
GestureDetector(
  child: FlutterMap(
    // ... your map configuration
  ),
  onTap: (tapPosition) => {
    // Access tappedPosition here
    LatLng tappedLatLng = mapController.convertScreenPointToLatLng(tapPosition);
    setState(() {
      markers.add(
        // ... your marker definition
      );
    });
  },
),
```